# Print without the print-specific CSS

Tags: css, firefox, pdf, printing

I'd like to print http://www.delicious.com/tags/engmark to PDF (Using Firefox on Linux, if possible), but the result looks rubbish. How can I print without taking into account the print-specific CSS (which I think is loaded by the enormous JS on the site)? I tried to disable print CSS in the [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/), but that didn't affect the print output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the HTML file and found that there's a link tag with the attribute of media="screen"

If you just remove that attribute, the CSS would then load.